# PHP efficiently write and output csv files using fputcsv

Tags: php, file, fputcsv

When writing .csv files i use fputcsv like this:

```
- open a temporary file $f = tmpfile();
- write content to file using fputcsv($f,$csv_row);
- send appropriate headers for attachment
- read file like this:

# move pointer back to beginning 
rewind($f);

while(!feof($f))
    echo fgets($f);

# fclose deletes temp file !
fclose($f);
```

Another aproach would be:

```
- open file $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
- send appropriate headers for attachment
- write content to file using fputcsv($f,$csv_row);
- close $f stream
```

#### My question is: What would be the best approach to output the data faster and taking into account server resources ?

First method would use more writes and consume more resources but would output very fast.

Second method uses less writes and would output slower i think.

Eagerly waiting for your opinions on this.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not about opinions. We don't *think* one or the other is faster. Try benchmarking both approaches, and you'll know which one is faster.

Comment: @BerryLangerak Yes, you are right. I'll try benchmarking this and post results.

Answer (score 0):

[fpassthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) will do what you're doing at a lower level. Use it like this:

```
# move pointer back to beginning 
rewind($f);

while(fpassthru($f) !== false);

# fclose deletes temp file !
fclose($f);
```

Even though it may be a csv file, there is no need to restrict yourself to csv functions, unless you are generating the file at the time of output.

You could probably see a performance gain if you stream the CSV to output instead of to a file.

Comment: I am generating a large .csv file from the database. It's always faster to use built-in functions offered by php. Thanks for fpassthru() ! I learned something today :).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to write the csv content to a tmp file/php's output stream ?

You just need to echo the csv content directly, **there should not be any file operations**.

- send appropriate headers for attachment
- echo the csv content.

---

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

foreach ($csv_rows as $csv_row) {
  echo $csv_row;
}
exit;
```

Comment: Because he uses fputcsv( ) to transform an arbitrary array to a CSV string. There is no stringtocsv function in PHP, afaik.

Comment: If `$csv_row` is an array, then you just need to implode it with the delimiter. `echo implode(',', $csv_row)."\n";`.

Comment: Actually, the CSV is wildly complex, and you're grossly underestimating it. For example, delimiters have to be escaped, as do the separator. If a value from an array is "foo, bar, baz", the implode idea will generate a broken CSV file. It's tougher than you think.

Comment: @BerryLangerak I know that. But you could always do the escape yourself, which is not complicated thing.

Comment: Yes, it *is* a complicated thing. But by all means; do try.

Comment: @berrylangerak My point is just you could not use a temp file, if you search this site, I am sure there are answers tell you how to turn array to csv string.

Comment: @xdazz Why reinvent the wheel when you have a good one ? fputcsv is way better and faster than manually escaping especially for large files. Berry Langerak is right.